# Extracting from Same table in many SQL Server Databases with same structure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 10 Source databases and I have two tables in all 10 databases with the same structure.
I need to extract data from all twenty tables in 10 databases into twenty tables in 10 databases.

It is a SQL Server environment and I prefer to use SSIS to accomplish this dynamically.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is connection string variables..  You'll want to assign a variable for the connection string portions you need, Server/database/credentials.  You'll need to capture of list of the 10 databases and do a foreach loop against the needed databases in the list.  Within the foreach loop you would use a dataflow or script tasks needed to select your data.

The following article provides a walkthrough of dynamic database connections;

http://sql-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/dynamic-database-connection-using-ssis.html

If both the source and the destinations are both variable you'll want to create two sets of variables. One variable set for source db and one for destination db and build matching pairs in your foreach list.